# How does 'this' keyword work in prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, this, prototype-chain

Hi experts here is my code and I'm stuck how `this` keyword is adding property to a object.

```
function carMaker(){
 this.companyName='Lamborghini'; 
 }
 let LamborghiniUrus = new carMaker();
 carMaker.prototype.country="Italy"
 LamborghiniUrus.price="200000";
```

I know property added with `this` and `Object.prototype` is inherited to all objects but does both are equivalent i.e, `this` is also adding property to prototype?

If **yes** then why `console.log(carMaker.prototype.companyName)` is undefined.

If **no** then how we can access a property added with `this`in the same object(in carMake fuction in my case).

And also does  `this.companyName='Lamborghini'` and `LamborghiniUrus.price="200000"` are equivalent.

Comment: You should do `LamborghiniUrus.prototype.country="Italy"`

Comment: "*property added with this is inherited to all objects*" - uh, no it is not?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar No, he should not. `LamborghiniUrus` is (despite the capitalised variable name) an instance and does not have a `.prototype` property.

Comment: @Bergi this.companyName is inheriting to LamborghiniUrus so I was thinking it is true in all caes

Comment: @MobeenSarwar No, there's no inheritance. The constructor does create an *own* property on the instance - a separate property on each separate object. Even if they all contain the same value.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain it for me in detail

Comment: @MobeenSarwar Do you know the difference between inherited properties and own properties?

Comment: @Bergi then what is inheritance. I's reading on blog that this is inheritance

Comment: @MobeenSarwar On which blog? Please post the link

Comment: all properties in object.prototype are inherited . Am I right? @Bergi

Comment: @MobeenSarwar Properties of the `SomeConstructor.prototype` object are inherited in objects created by  `new SomeConstructor`, yes.

Comment: @Bergi have a look on on this MDN link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: @Bergi i got your point (Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In combination with `new`, `this` refers to the object you are creating.

So `this.companyName='Lamborghini'` sets a property on the actual instance.

When you try to **read** a property from an object, it first attempts to read the property from the object itself. If it doesn't find one, it looks up the prototype chain until it finds an object with that property (or runs out of prototypes).

Writing a property to an object doesn't touch anything up the prototype chain.

Comment: how I can access companyName in carMaker? is it possible in anyway?

Comment: @MobeenSarwar — You **are** accessing it. That's why you can set it.

Comment: I want this statement to run console.log(carMaker.prototype.companyName) but this returns undefined

Comment: @MobeenSarwar — Yes, I explained why in the final paragraph. If you want a modification to Lamborghini to affect *all* car manufacturers then you are doing something wrong. Changes to all car manufacturers should be made on the object representing all car manufacturers and then inherited down. Not the other way around.

Comment: does this.companyName='Lamborghini' and LamborghiniUrus.price="200000" are equivalent ? Yes or No

Comment: I'm too much confused about both of these statements

Comment: `LamborghiniUrus` and `this` might refer to the same object depending on context. `.companyName` and `.price`  are different properties. `'Lamborghini'` and `"200000"` are different values.

Comment: I know .companyName and .price are different properties but my question is---does adding properties with both these methods is same?

Comment: Maybe. The value of `this` depends on context as I said.